# Clang (in Xcode): start with -Weverything and manually disable particular warnings

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang

I like to use `-Weverything` for the compiler to catch all possible warnings, but sometimes I get warnings that I don't want to fix. How can I manually disable those particular warnings as they occur?

Comment: Note that your approach isn't really the best way to go about things: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/122608/clang-warning-flags-for-objective-c-development/124574#124574

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can disable individual warnings using `-Wno-XYZ`, XYZ being the name of the warning feature to be disabled.

Comment: Ok, but do you know how I get the correct `XYZ` from the yellow warning bubble in Xcode? Please bring back "Xcode" to the question. It was an important part of it :)

Comment: @7cows No, this isn't really an Xcode question, you want to set **compiler** flags. Well, there's a manual for `clang` which lists all switches and options, including warnings. Here you are: [link](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#individual-warning-groups)

Comment: @7cows Don't put `xcode` back to the tags, this **really isn't** an Xcode question. Also, you're not supposed to put the answer into the question - that's why we have separate posts for answers.

Answer (score 17):

[image: XCode]

In XCode 5 I had to build, then right click on an issue and select "Reveal in Log" then set the Middle Pane tab to "All" too get the issues displayed in the log.

Then clicking on the "Hamburger" Icon to the right and scrolling down I finally got an exact description of the Warning.

```
/.../SettingsViewController.m:91:58: warning: creating selector for nonexistent method 'setSegueIdentifier:' [-Wselector]
    [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector(setSegueIdentifier:)
```

So in my case the following does the job.

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wselector"
...
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: I've been looking for how to find the flag specific to the compiler warning for a while now! Thanks for this - very useful!

Answer (score 3):

I just bumped into a site that lists all Clang warnings and the flags that disable them (using `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wxyz"`):

http://goo.gl/hwwIUa (when you visit it you'll understand why I've shortened the URL).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you know how to update the build settings to enable/disable individual warnings and want to disable the warning in your code. Here is an example:

```
#ifdef TESTFLIGHT_USERTRACKING

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-implementations"

[TestFlight setDeviceIdentifier:[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]];

#pragma clang diagnostic pop

#endif
```